# Removing gedit without removing all of cinnamon-desktop-environment

Tags: apt, desktop-environment, cinnamon, gedit

I don't like gedit and always use geany or vim or something else. Removing it from my current Debian testing install also removes the `cinnamon-desktop-environment` meta package because it depends on gedit. This meta package:

> depends on all programs needed to have a fully fledged desktop environment. Install this if you want a complete cinnamon desktop, including graphical apps that allow users to perform almost all everyday tasks.

After removing it, apt shows that 209 packages are no longer necessary (because nothing depends on them) including Pidgin, LibreOffice, Gnome System Monitor, etc. Next time I want to run autoremove for another uninstalled application, it would remove all of them.

I guess the solution is to manually `apt-get install` the packages I actually want to have (i.e. Pidgin, LibreOffice, System Monitor, etc.), but there are also a bunch of packages of which I have no idea what they do. Many of them are probably dependencies of the aforementioned, but I don't know. I'd have to check them all manually. Some look unrelated, like `t1utils` (`apt-cache rdepends` doesn't show anything I recognize).

Another "solution" is to `apt-get install` the whole list of packages that it would otherwise autoremove, but that's an ugly hack because it would no longer know which packages were installed because of dependencies and which were installed because I want them to be installed.

I could also modify `cinnamon-desktop-environment` (e.g. by creating my own `.deb`) in some way that it doesn't depend on gedit while maintaining the other dependencies. I'm not sure how exactly, but it doesn't sound too hard. The issue with this is that it probably does not update anymore when there are updates because I installed a custom version of it.

Thinking about creating my own package, I looked into `cinnamon-desktop-environment`'s dependencies. Surprise: it depends on firefox, which is not even available in Debian. And it depends on iceweasel, which I already uninstalled with no trouble. I don't understand.

How do I go about removing gedit without messing up my desktop environment?

Comment: It depends on `iceweasel | firefox | chromium | gnome-www-browser`, so as long as one of them is installed, the dependency is not broken.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That explains one thing, thanks! Still though, the main question remains: how to remove gedit? Looking at the dependencies again, there are no alternatives it accepts.

Comment: Why do you want to remove gedit? If you don't want to use it, don't use it.

Comment: "I guess the solution is to manually apt-get install the packages I actually want to have (i.e. Pidgin, LibreOffice, System Monitor, etc.), but there are also a bunch of packages of which I have no idea what they do. Many of them are probably dependencies of the aforementioned, but I don't know. I'd have to check them all manually.".Yes, just manually install the packages you want, and don't manually install packages you don't know / don't care about. Why would you install packages you don't know?

Comment: *"If you don't want to use it, don't use it"* I also don't want unnecessary bloat on my system. It's like on default Windows installs where you get a bunch of trial software, there too you could say the same.

Comment: *"Why would you install packages you don't know?"* Perhaps they perform a function I don't know of, e.g. `t1utils` seems to do something with fonts, some other utility might need it. Or it might be a dependency of a dependency. I just don't know.

Comment: @FaheemMitha If I have a package that I don't use, I will terminate with cancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing a program just because you don't use it shows a misguided sense of priorities. Disk space is cheap. Gedit takes less than 2MB of disk space. Even at SSD RAID-1 prices, that costs less than ½¢. At the minimum wage in my country, it takes less than 2s to earn that much. It'll take you far more than 2 seconds to do this. The gains from removing the package are negligible — only the network and disk bandwidth when the package is installed.

That being said, here's how you can do it.

---

The `cinnamon-desktop-environment` package depends on the applications that are officially part of the Cinnamon desktop environment. Gedit is one of them.

If you want to remove Gedit but keep the rest of Cinnamon, mark the dependencies of `cinnamon-desktop-environment` except `gedit` as manually installed, then remove `cinnamon-desktop-environment`. You take the responsibility of adding any component that might be added to Cinnamon in the future. You can use [aptitude search](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html) to list the packages that Cinnamon depends on.

```
aptitude unmarkauto $(aptitude -F %p search '~i ~Rcinnamon-desktop-environment !^gedit$')
apt-get remove gedit
```

Alternatively, you could make a fake `gedit` package that exists solely to resolve the dependency but doesn't contain the gedit binary. You can [use equivs to make such fake packages](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.building-first-package.html). Note that some Cinnamon configuration may still believe that Gedit is present and attempt to call the nonexistent binary.

Comment: Responding specifically to first paragraph of this answer: time is precious. Each of us has exactly 24 hours of it each day, so spending it well is important. Some of us don't want our apt update to take longer than it has to, even if we have unlimited bandwidth and storage.

Comment: @sowbug Which is why you should keep the package installed. [You'll never get back the time it would take you to figure out how to uninstall the package](https://xkcd.com/1205/).